# Unity play video on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video-streaming

How do you make unity can run video through android ?

Remember that unity video can not run into android.

Or if there any asset package that can make unity video can run through Android, What is the asset package name ? Where i can find it ? Preferred is free. And How to use it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most devices, you can use [MovieTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html), but according to the docs,

> Movie Textures are not supported on Android. Instead, full-screen streaming playback is provided using Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html) this method.

If you have a budget, you can try [Easy Movie Texture](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032), currently priced at $65. I haven't used it myself, but it shows a video demo running on an Android device and the reviews all seem positive.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have already try Easy Movie Texture, but when i run unity remote 5 through my mobile, the video was not played. I don't know if i have do mistake or not. Where I can find the documentation ?

Comment: Your best bet is to contact the seller.  According to the comments the author is pretty responsive.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Handheld to play video:

```
string url; //Contains the path to your video
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie(url, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.Fill);
```

In order to get more info, check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html)